# Probability: The planet Kepler-166 has an orbital period of 229 days. Consider a group of 20 inhabitants on this planet. . .

Tags: probability

What is the probability that at least 2 of them share a birthday?

I'm going to try using PIE (that I just learned):

P(20) = 1 - P (all different) =$1-\frac{^{229}P_{20}}{229^{20}}$?

Does that look about right? Could I proceed from there?

Comment: That looks right, assuming Kepler-166 has a rotational period of one Earth day.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's assumed to be that way, yes.